Out-of-Tree platform in React native Expo
I know React Native supports Out-of-Tree platform but I'm working with expo and I'm not sure how to implement it as Expo doesn't allow me to export to any platform outside android/ios/web.
The idea is to export two web platforms (one for web and another one for electron) with different dependencies (at the moment aptabase web and aptabase electron but could be usefull for other platforms like sunmi devices). Does anyone knows how to customize expo export to use something like expo export -p electron to extend web but allow use xx.electron.ts
